# Apache BigTop testing step by step instructions

Tags: testing, hadoop, bigtop

I trying to understand how Apache BigTop works and how we can run the test cases. Even though some information is given [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/BIGTOP/Setting+up+Bigtop+to+run+HBase+system+tests), still it is not much clear on the aspects like - How Test Artifacts/Executions work? How can I modify test cases? How POM file works?

Where can I find the exact flowchart for a beginner like me?